# new navbar containing logo and social icons that only appears scrolling past my actual navbar

Tags: scroll, navbar

I can't find a tutorial for making a second navbar that only appears after scrolling past the actual navbar and contains logo to the left, nav links centered and social icons and search form to the right.

Right now, I only fixed the widget of my navbar to top, but I'd like to add it extra elements.
My site: www.macamartinez.com

Any help or clue will be most welcome!

Many Thanks!